# how to know when flatlist goes out of viewport in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen which contains a list of items that is being shown using flatlist, th flatlist is as below :

```
  <FlatList
        scrollEnabled
        removeClippedSubviews
        windowSize={21}
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayoutFun}
        ListHeaderComponent={listFTUEHeader}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        data={DISCOVERY_SECTION_LIST}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onRefresh={onRefresh}
        refreshing={false}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        ListFooterComponent={EndOfListText}
        onScroll={onScroll}
      />
```

I want to detect when the ListHeaderComponent is out of viewport or item[1] is at the top of the screen, accordingly I want to add a state.

I have read the documentation but could not find a way, hopefully would get any leads from here.

Any leads would be helpful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same situation, so far i only could find a solution to check, if a specific item is in the viewport, but nothing about the ListHeaderComponent.

FlatList has a prop called `onViewableItemsChanged` which you can easily implement. When you scroll a FlatList, the items showing on the FlatList change. Then, this function is called, telling you what current viewableItems are and what changed items are.

See also [this article](https://suelan.github.io/2020/01/21/onViewableItemsChanged/) for further explanation.

Maybe this helps you to get closer to a solution which works for you?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this as well and this is the best option I've found so far:

1. Get the height of the header

- If you know the height on all screen sizes, create a variable to reuse
- If not, use the `onLayout` prop to get the height

2. Use the `onScroll` callback and get the y offtset via `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y`

Did you ever end up finding another solution for this?